# how to retrieve element from Elements in Java from a HTML

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsoup

If i have code like this

```
Elements e = d.select("div[id=result_52]");
System.out.println("elemeeeeeee" + e);
```

the output of e is as below

```
elemeeeeeee<imagebox id="result_52" class="rsltGrid prod celwidget" name="B00BF9MZ44"> 
<div class="linePlaceholder"></div>
    <div class="image imageContainer"> 
        <a href="http://www.abcdefg.com/VIZIO-E241i-A1-24-Inch-1080p-tilted/dp/B00BF9MZ44/ref=lp_6459736011_1_53/190-4904523-2326018?s=tv&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1405599829&amp;sr=1-53">
    <div class="imageBox"> 
    <img src="http://ecx.images-abcdefg.com/images/I/51PhLnnk7NL._AA160_.jpg" class="productImage cfMarker" alt="Product Details" /> 
</div>
```

I want both URL which is coming inside

Comment: do you want to get URLs from `href` and `src` attributes?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `#` to get the specific `id`.

```
Element e = d.select("div#result_52").get(0);
String firstURL = e.select("a").attr("href"); //select the `a` tag and the `href` attribute.
String secondURL = e.select("img").attr("src");
```

Comment: why cant we give like this Elements e = d.select("div[id=result_52]");
and using Element e = d.select("div#result_52").get(0); instead

Comment: is there any difference in both ?

Comment: there is no diffrence between select("div[id=result_52]"); and select("div#result_52"); but of course .get(0) makes a difference. If you don't use this, it will bring all the elements which id=result_52. But if you use get(0) it will bring the first one.